Root element must be declared in the DTD
I have an XML document with the DTD:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE company [
        ]>
<company>
</company>

And I get the warning:

Element type "company" must be declared.

But company is the root element.  Why must I declare it?

Because being the root element says nothing about what its content model may be. You've said company should be the top-level element; you've not said what attributes, element children, or text children it may have.
So, either remove the DOCTYPE to create a well-formed XML document,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company>
</company>

or add a declaration for company such as,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE company [
  <!ELEMENT company (#PCDATA)>
]>
<company>
</company>

See also

Is there any difference between 'valid xml' and 'well formed xml'?
What is the difference between root node, root element and document element in XML?


Thank you, you've really helped me
